Question about sequence of Thirty-Second notes
I have this section of piano sheet music that I am really confused with. It contains a sequence of thirty-second notes that maybe have a tremolo. I don't understand what the line under the G on the bass clef and above the E signify. Would anyone be able to tell me which notes need to be played and with which hand?  
